# Do pistons in tinkers construct villages serve a purpose?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-tinkers-construct

When villages are generated by Feed The Beast with Tinkers Construct, they sometimes have workshops with TC crafting stations and a piston.  Does the piston serve a purpose or are the for decoration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pistons in Tinkers' Construct generated villages are not connected to anything and aren't useful where they start off.

However villagers with this mod will sometimes accept pistons as currency instead of emeralds,  so they are useful in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

Pistons can used for the knockback modifier, and as currency as said in the comment before. Also when playing in modpacks, there's a chance it can be used in a crafting recipie.

ex: FTB Unleashed